# is there a way to have templates in react

Tags: reactjs

I have built an element which is kind of template. (e.g, thumbnail container with image at the top and something in the footer with dynamic content between them)
the dynamic content can be different types of DOM elements, based on the state.
I did it with adding logic in the render method which "injects" the dynamic part. 
Does this make sense (having logic in the render method which returns different react components)?
Is there a better way for templating? (i'm not looking for projects that add this capability, wanted to know if there's a "react way" to do so.
Thanks!

edit: here's the code I was referring to (coffeescript):

```
internalContent: ->
  switch @props.title
    when "title1" then SomeReactFactory(props)
    when "title2" then SomeOtherReactFactory(props)

render ->
  ...
  DOM.div
    className: 'panel'
    @internalContent()
```

the `internalContent()` method is dynamically adding some React Component based on the prop

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. If you were to post code it would be easier to give you specific advice - but this is a common practice.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: i think you are describing HOC's in react. Look them up

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers, I have edited my question to the exact code I have...

Answer (score 0):

This is the React way.. And you should make use of it to target your specific domain.

For example a Button in React could be written like this:

```
const MyButton = ({ text, type = "normal", color = "blue", onClick }) => {
   return (
      <button
        onClick={onClick}
        style={{backgroundColor: color }} 
        className={"my-button my-button--type" + type}>
           {text}
     </button>);
};
```

Or a layout component:

```
const MyLayout = ({side, nav, main}) => {
   return (
      <div className="container">
        <nav>{nave}</nav>
        <aside>{side}</aside>
        <div className="main">{main}</div>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Now you can composite it for example like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    <MyLayout
       nav={<MyNav/>}
       side={<MySideBar items={...} />}
       main={<MyButton onClick={this.onClick} text="Main Button"}
    />
  }
}
```

Dont try to pack everything in a big Component which will do everything, the trick in React is to make small reusable Components and composite them.

You could also create a bunch of components which you can use across many projects.

Comment: Hi @webdeb.
Thanks for the reply. this makes sense to me. if you look at my edited question (I have added the code), I was referring to the logic I have in the `render` method, which in your example would be to have a method with logic inside your `main` (replacing the `<MyButton...` with a method for defining what `React` elements to insert there

Comment: @RoyZinn yes, you can do it this way. After you feel that the rendered markup/code could be reused somewhere else you can create a separate component..